# Remove default value from NOT NULL column

Tags: mysql

I have an existing `NOT NULL` column which has a default value. I want to remove the default value so that the user is forced to enter a value.

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE items;
CREATE TABLE `items` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

However, when I try to modify the column and set the default to null, mysql throws an error:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE items MODIFY ordering INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL;
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'ordering'
```

How can I remove the default from this column without having to do something crazy like change it to nullable, then remove the default, then change it back to not null?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use the following (slightly odd) syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE items ALTER ordering DROP DEFAULT;
```

Answer (score 2):

When trying to modify a column with `ALTER TABLE`, there are 4 keywords that can be used, each with different capabilities:

- `CHANGE [COLUMN]`
- `MODIFY [COLUMN]`
- `RENAME COLUMN`
- `ALTER [COLUMN]`

`CHANGE` is a MySQL extension to standard SQL. `MODIFY` and `RENAME COLUMN` are MySQL extensions for Oracle compatibility.

`ALTER [COLUMN]` is standard SQL (I think).

The docs about [**`ALTER TABLE`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) have more details:

> **Renaming, Redefining, and Reordering Columns**
>
> The `CHANGE`, `MODIFY`, `RENAME COLUMN`, and `ALTER` clauses enable the names
>   and definitions of existing columns to be altered. They have these
>   comparative characteristics:
>
> - `CHANGE`:
>
>   - **Can** rename a column and **change its definition**, or both.
>   - Has more capability than `MODIFY` or `RENAME COLUMN`, but at the expense of convenience for some operations. `CHANGE` **requires naming
>       the column twice if not renaming it, and requires respecifying the
>       column definition if only renaming it**.
>   - With `FIRST` or `AFTER`, can reorder columns.
> - `MODIFY`:
>
>   - **Can change a column definition** but not its name.
>   - More convenient than `CHANGE` to change a column definition without renaming it.
>   - With `FIRST` or `AFTER`, can reorder columns.
> - `RENAME COLUMN`:
>
>   - Can change a column name but not its definition.
>   - More convenient than `CHANGE` to rename a column without changing its definition.
> - `ALTER`:
>
>   - Used only **to change a column default value**.

---

In this case, you have 3 options:

```
ALTER TABLE items
    CHANGE ordering ordering int NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE items 
    MODIFY ordering int NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE items
    ALTER ordering DROP DEFAULT ;
```

Comment: I never noticed that `CHANGE`/`MODIFY` remove the default if it is not specified! I'm amazed that hasn't bitten me yet.